# Referencing SVG with <img> vs <image>

Tags: css, image, svg

I noticed there are two ways to reference SVG images. You can either use the standard `<img>` tag

```html
<img src="picture.svg" alt="SVG Image"/>
```

or you can use [`<image>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag) tag

```html
<svg>
   <image xlink:href="picture.svg" x="0" y="0" height="50px" width="50px"/>
</svg>
```

To me, it seems better to simply use the `<img>` tag because you get the `alt` attribute which makes it more search friendly and you also can apply styles via CSS. I was having trouble applying styles because the SVG `<image>` requires attributes.

I was wondering if there was a significant reason why you would use the SVG `<image>` tag over the standard `<img>`?

Comment: The equivalent to alt in an SVG image tag is to use a child `<desc>` element. An image tag only works within SVG and img only works within html.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for that! Wow they even work with [screen readers](http://www.iheni.com/just-how-accessible-is-svg/) :) Really appreciate that info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<svg>` element is used for putting inline SVG in your document. So in this case, if you want to avoid having to load an external file, you can put the contents of `picture.svg` directly between the `<svg>` and `</svg>` tags.

If that's not the intended purpose, and you just want to show an image that happens to be in SVG format, there's no real reason to put in inside an SVG block; just use `<img>`.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that I didn't say you _should_ use an `<img>`. Using an SVG `<image>` would do just fine; it's just not necessary in the case where there's no other SVG.

Comment: Yeah thank you for that clarification. I guess to be specific about my use case, we wanted to shrink an SVG image when a user when to mobile. We could have used JS to edit the attributes directly on the `<image>` tag, but by switching to `<img>` instead, we could just use media queries and change the CSS width and height when they hit that screen size. Saves a lot of pain for something really simple.